# Regular expression not working Sybase ASE 16.0

Tags: sql, regex, sybase, sap-ase

I am trying to retrieve IDs from a table in Sybase ASE 16.0

The query has to return IDs starting with AB or BC. Example
AB0001
AB0002
BC0001
BC0002

The regular expression in my query is not working

Select * from T1 where id like '(AB|BC)%'

The above query is not working. Can someone suggest the correct regex statement that works in ASE.

Answer (score 4):

ASE 16 doesn't support this kind of regex like.
Please try below SQL:

```
select * from T1 where id like 'AB%' or col2 like 'BC%'
```